# MVC DropDownListFor Edit Modal Not Returning SelectedValue

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have a DropDownListFor field on my Edit modal popup, which is a partial view.  The Type field in my model is an int.  I have the field disabled as I do not want the user to be able to edit that field.

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, ViewData["TypeList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Type)
   </div>
</div>
```

The Edit data is populated via a combination of a JsonResult return and JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showModalEdit(learningObjectId) {
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit")/' + learningObjectId,
                //context: JSON.stringify({ id: moduleId })
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data.LearningObject && data.LearningObject.Name) {
                    document.getElementById("LearningObjectID").value = learningObjectId;
                    document.getElementById("Name").value = data.LearningObject.Name;
                    document.getElementById("DisplayName").value = data.LearningObject.DisplayName;
                    document.getElementById("Description").value = data.LearningObject.Description;
                    document.getElementById("Type").value = data.LearningObject.TypeCode;
                    document.getElementById("ImportID").value = data.LearningObject.ImportID;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Tags.length; i++) {
                        addTag('Tags', 'tagInputEdit', 'tagListEdit', 'tagCountEdit', data.Tags[i].Name);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
</script>

public JsonResult Edit(int? id)
{
      LearningObject learningObject = _db.LearningObjects.Find(id);
      var tags = (from t in _db.Tags
                  join lot in _db.LearningObjectTags on t.TagID equals lot.TagID
                  where lot.LearningObjectID == id.Value && lot.Active == true
                  select new { Name = t.Name }).ToList();

       return Json(new { LearningObject = learningObject, Tags = tags }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In doing my research, I read that the best way to return the value of a disabled DropDownListFor to the Controller is via a hidden field, which I implemented in my partial view.  When I click the Edit modal, the correct value displays in the disabled DropDownListFor, but when I submit the form, the model returns to the controller with a value of 0.

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like you’re populating only the disabled dropdown and not the hidden field. The getElementById selector will let populate one field only, as the Id attribute is supposed to be unique